# Javascript POST hook

Tags: javascript, http, http-post, dom-events

I've got an web page up and running, and I'm wondering if it is possible to make an event listener that gets all of the HTTP POST or GET or PUT events.
So, what I want to do is when the user clicks a submit button on my website or clicks on a link, a Javascript function is triggered so that I can get the params in the http request.

What I want to do is check the parameters from an http request and under certain conditions send another, different http request.

Comment: There's an event called onsubmit that binds to a form that will let you manipulate your controls before it is actually POSTed. At time of fire the POST data isn't yet collected (I think, feel free to interject and prove me wrong). I also think this even't won't fire if the submit is done via JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an event handler to all of your forms and links on the page:

```
var myHandler = function(e) {
// Do what you want here
};

$('a').click(myHandler);
$('form').submit(myHandler);
```

Comment: I could do that, but I was hoping that that I could make one event and not have to add it to all the links and forms.

Comment: @Jay Assuming you use [`event.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) rather than `return false;` (or [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)) in existing bindings, you can use event bubbling and bind once to the `document`: `$(document).submit(myHandler);`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, that works, if you put that as an answer, I can select it as the answer